# python program can't run in cmd

Tags: python, import

there is a python programe in `c:\workspace\trutle.py`,
i can run it in the python command line console,
when i open a cmd window, input `python  c:\workspace\trutle.py`,
i get the wrong output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\workspace\turtle.py", line 1, in <module>  
    import turtle
  File "c:\workspace\turtle.py", line 3, in <module>  
    turtle.speed(1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'speed'
```

what is the reason? how to solve it?

```
import turtle
from random import randint
turtle.speed(1)
turtle.color("grey")
x=-80
for y in range(-80,80+1,10):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(160)


y=80
turtle.right(90)
for x in range(-80,80+1,10):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(160
```

Comment: Is your file named `turtle.py` or `trutle.py`?  If it's named `turtle`, then when you do `import turtle` it will try to import itself.  Name it something else besides a standard lib name.

Comment: i renamed it trutle_test.py,everything is ok.

Answer (score 3):

Rename the `turtle.py`. Otherwise it prevent importing the [`turtle`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) module.

Make sure to delete `turtle.pyc` generated.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the filename `turtle.py` to some other name.This may block the functionality of the   default method.